# Как обновить анимацию после перестроения сборки в Компас-3D?

Tags: анимация, сборка, компас-3d

У меня была определенная сборка в Компас-3Д. На этой сборке я построил анимацию. После этого одну из деталей сборки я видоизменил (поменял ее ориентацию). Запускаю анимацию. Анимация сама возвращает сборку к исходному состоянию (то есть, меняет ориентацию детали обратно). Что можно сделать, чтобы анимация не меняла сборку?